# Getting the text based on context in webkit

Tags: javascript, webkit, gtk, range, pygtk

I am working on scraping robot where I have to scrape web pages and "infer" the contents.

What I have:

1. Webkit/python API available on Ubntu and it's full API including DOM access and manipulation
2. A web page I don't control
3. An interesting text input field as webkit returns it.
4. Controlled environment for browser - window size/hardware is known.

What I want to do:

Get the text that is closest and visually before the input box. This roughly translates into clicking just before input box and going up 3/4 lines or around 1 inch on the screen if you are going do it manually. I can say 1 inch since I do control window size and other hardware.

Problem:

Because of DOM hierarchy and CSS positioning text visually closer may not be always closer in page markup. How do I simulate text selection as if user is doing it manually?

Tried ranges, but the problem is getting right elements as ranges need start/end elements. Besides for some reason I am getting javascript/comments other fluff back when I do it programatically, but does not happen when I do it manually on the screen and inspect the range browser has.